# c# memory leak in loop

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

```
public void DoPing(object state)
{
    string host = state as string;
    m_lastPingResult = false;
    while (!m_pingThreadShouldStop.WaitOne(250))
    {
        Ping p = new Ping();
        try
        {
            PingReply reply = p.Send(host, 3000);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                m_lastPingResult = true;
            }
            else
            {
                m_lastPingResult = false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        numping = numping + 1;
    }
}
```

Any idea why this code gives me a memory leak? I can see it's this code as changing the wait value to smaller or larger values increases the rate of the memory usage. Does any one have any idea how to resolve it? or how to see what part of the code is causing it?

Comment: How do you tell that this code has a memory leak?

Comment: Please help yourself by never writing `catch { }` again.

Comment: You can try to dispose `Ping`

Comment: becasue when I run it and it enters this loop I can see memory usage climbing at in time with the wait command.

Comment: oh would that do it Kirk? I Agree I don't like catch either, this is still a work in progress and already had the try / catch methods

Comment: The garbage collector probably hasn't gotten around to cleaning up your stuff yet.

Comment: @DevilWAH: As Marlon says: climbing memory usage != memory leak (unless it keeps climbing for a couple of days or so).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some garbage collected languages, there is a limitation that the object isn't collected if the method that created it still hasn't exited.

I believe .net works this way in debug mode. Quoting from this article; note the bolded statement.

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-.net/

> A local variable in a method that is currently running is considered
>   to be a GC root. The objects referenced by these variables can always
>   be accessed immediately by the method they are declared in, and so
>   they must be kept around. The lifetime of these roots can depend on
>   the way the program was built. **In debug builds, a local variable lasts
>   for as long as the method is on the stack.** In release builds, the JIT
>   is able to look at the program structure to work out the last point
>   within the execution that a variable can be used by the method and
>   will discard it when it is no longer required. This strategy isn’t
>   always used and can be turned off, for example, by running the program
>   in a debugger.

Comment: Oh. And as other's noted, Ping is IDisposable so you must .Dispose it. I'd recommend using(Ping ping = new Ping()) { }

Comment: You don't *have* to call Dispose on it. The garbage collector will call the finalizer which should call Dispose in case you forgot to dispose it yourself. However, you *should* call Dispose on it, or rather use a `using (...) {}`, to free up resources immediately when you are done with them.

Comment: @sethcall: The quotation doesn't imply that an object "isn't collected if the method that created it still hasn't exited."  In this case, once a new `Ping` is assigned to `p`, the previous `Ping` instance is no longer rooted, *because it is no longer referenced by any local variable,* and it is eligible for collection.

Comment: "Must" is overstating a bit.  The app will use less resources if you do, and doesn't run the risk of running out of unmanaged resource handles before the next GC...but a GC will end up reclaiming those resources, considering MS's stuff correctly implements the Disposable pattern.

Comment: In my case I am calling this code in an ansyc mode with up to 50+ instances, so I think clearing up as I go along will be a good idea :)

Comment: @phoog  A good GC would behave that way, but that quotation reads to me : a local variable stays around until the method exits, in a debug build, regardless  if it's no longer referenced.  Whether it's correct or not requires a simple test.

Comment: @sethcall You are misreading the quotation.  Note that a key point in its line of reasoning is "objects referenced by these variables...". A variable is not the same thing as the object to which it refers. There is only one local Ping variable in the method. It can only refer to one object at a time. Any object to which it does not refer is eligible for GC.

Comment: @sethcall A simple test: if your reasoning is correct, the following method will throw an out of memory exception in debug mode: void TryIt() { while (true) { object o = new object (); } }

Comment: @phoog it does not on mono.  I tried in debug and release.  I didn't try on windows.net.

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collection only happens when there is memory pressure, thus just seeing your memory usage go up doesn't mean there is a memory leak <s>and in this code I don't see how there could be a legitimate leak.</s> You can add

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

to double check but shouldn't leave that in production.

Edit: someone in comments pointed out that Ping is Disposable.  not calling dispose can cause leaks that will eventually get cleaned up but may take a long time and cause non memory related problems.

Comment: may be thats it, I was just supised to see that after about 5min of the loop it was using about 300mb abd climbing

Comment: @DevilWAH Was your computer under memory pressure? If not, there's no reason for the GC to run.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `finally` statement to your `try-catch`, like this:

```
catch() {}
finally
{
     Ping.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: It's really bad to see `catch {}` making it into an answer.

Comment: should use `using` as it is less error prone and definitly shouldn't use the Diaper anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
using(var p = new Ping())
{
    try
    {
        var reply = p.Send(host, 3000);

        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
           _lastPingResult = true;
        else  
           _lastPingResult = false; 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: `PingReply` is not `IDisposable`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is  You just commented above that it was.

Comment: No, I said Ping is IDisposable.

Comment: @ta.speot.is O ok, sorry bout that

Answer (score 0):

This can be used from a static Class:

```
public static bool testNet(string pHost, int pTimeout)
{
    Ping p = new Ping();

    bool isNetOkay = false;

    int netTries = 0;

    do
    {
        PingReply reply = p.Send(pHost, pTimeout);

        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            isNetOkay = true;
            break;
        }

        netTries++;

    } while (netTries < 4);

    //Void memory leak

    p.Dispose();

    return isNetOkay;
}
```