# whats the best way to test multiple boxes for ping quickly

Tags: c#, monitoring, ping

I have an application where I monitor and control a bunch of computers (probably 3 to 35 or so, probably local).

One of the things I monitor is uptime/ping status. One of the application's purposes is to restart the boxes, sometimes they restart for other reasons.

I'd like to be able pick up the pingable/non-pingable changes quickly.

I have a spin loop on a thread.

It seems to me that blocking ping prevents it from updating for a bit even if you run it in parallel(prevent one box's ping from blocking another)

(parallel implementation example, note the following is just of the top of my head and hasn't been implemented, may contain errors)

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now;
var period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds();
Parallel.ForEach(boxes, (box) => 
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var remainingTime = (now - startTime) - period;
    while(remainingTime > TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        box.CanPing.TryUpdate();
    }
});
```

where TryUpdate is just something like

```
using(ping = new Ping())
{
    var reply = ping.Send (IP);
    bool upStatus = (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success);
    this.Value = upStatus;
}
```

Alternatively I tried using multiple SendAsync (multiple async pings at one time) to discover uptime as quickly as possible with Double-checked locking in the callback to SendAsync

```
if(upStatus != this.Value)
{
    lock(_lock)//is it safe to have a non static readonly lock object, all the examples seem to use a static object but that wouldn't scale to  locking in multiple instances of the containing class object
    {
        if(upStatus != this.Value)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

it was an awful memory leak but that may be because I'm making too many async ping calls (which each come with a thread) too quickly, and not disposing of ping. If I limit myself to 3 per computers at a time, or put a longer pause in the middle, and Dispose() the ping do you think it would be a good idea?

What's the better strategy? Any other ideas?

Comment: So I thought this is such an interesting question, a lot of bounty, and yet there's not too much attention given. It's a pity, since all those stupid questions asked all the time get 10 answers in 5 minutes and usually noone actually gains anything from them.

Comment: Keep in mind that Parallel.ForEach is throttled. Threads are allocated every half second or so.

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846500/c-sharp-memory-leak-in-loop

Comment: Parallel.ForEach uses the default thread pool.  As Amir said, by default, it starts out throttled.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads.aspx

You can alter the default ThreadPool by calling SetMinThreads.  If you set it to your number of boxes (with some sane upper limit) you will launch the pings much faster.

Comment: So what did you end up doing? How did it work out?

Answer (score 8):

This is a specific case of multithreading, where you do not need the treads to make the program faster, you need to make it more responsive. Your operations take little to none computing power. Therefore I would not be scared to create a single thread for each monitored computer. They are going to be doing `sleep()` most of the time anyway. They should be created once, because the thread creation is actually the most expensive thing here.

I would create object hierarchy like that:

- `GUIProxy` - would handle all gui operations, like changing notification colors next to coputer's name
- `HostManager` - would register new machines, remove old, perform timing checks on `Monitors`
- `HostMonitor` - would periodically, sequentially send pings to check computers. More on it's behavior later

### Checking algorithm

In LANs most of the time pings return within 1-2 ms of sending. Over the Internet the time may vary.
I would have two ping-time thresholds set separately for each `Monitor`, depending on the machine location. One would be a "warning" threshold (yellow light or sth in GUI) when the LAN ping is greater than 5ms or Internet ping > 200ms. The second would be an "error" threshold, with LAN>1s and Internet >2s or sth.
Each `Monitor` would send ping, wait for an answer, and send another ping after receiving an answer. It should store `lastPingSendTime`, `lastPingReceiveTime` and `currentPingSendTime`. The former are for determining latency, the latter is for checking the delay in `HostManager`. Of course the `Monitor` should handle timeouts and other system/network events properly.

In `HostManager`, also running on a single thread, I would check the `currentPingSendTime` on each Monitor and check it against that monitor's thresholds. If a threshold is crossed, the `GUIProxy` would be notified to show the situation in GUI.

Advantages

- you control threads yourself
- you can use [synchronous(simpler) ping method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb7xxkfx.aspx)
- `Manager` will not hang, since it accesses Monitors asynchronously
- You can implement an abstract Monitor interface which you could use to monitor other things, not only computers

Disadvantages

- correct `Monitor` threading implementation may not be simple

Comment: Totally agree. I think this is the most responsive and provides a simple approach. 
HostMonitor could raise an event like "OnSystemDown" or so to do the notification so that actions can be taken when a ping times out.

Answer (score 2):

Depending if you require a scale out solution you could implement the state checking like Dariusz said (which is an absolute legitimate Approach).

This Approach has only one disadvantage which may or may not be relevant in your Scenario:
scaling up to hundrets or even thousands of monitored boxes or Services will result in a huge amount of threads. regarding the fact that .net applications in 64bit mode Support several thousand concurrent threads i would not recomment to spawn that much workers. the resource Scheduler won't be your best friend anymore if you give him the Job to schedule such a huge amount of workers.

In order to get a scale out capable solution it's a Little more difficult.
Let's get shortly back to the original Problem: You want to Monitor a bunch of boxes quickly and pipelined processing is not performing well.
Concering that you may Monitor other Services (tcp) in future also waiting for timeouts would kill this Approach completely.

**Solution: Custom thread pooling or thread reusage**

As you're dealing with a Special sort of threading which is influenced by the time a thread is spawned from the Default thread pool a solution is required to get rid of the spawning issue. having in mind to be able to scale out i would recommend this way:

Use a custom or the Default thread pool to spawn up several threads which are in suspended state. 
Now you're System wants to measure several boxes. Therefore: Get to you prewarmed threads and take the first suspended / free one and reserve it for your Monitoring Job.
After you gained the thread for your usage you give him some sort of handle to your actual worker method (which will be invoked asynchronously by the thread). 
After the Monitoring Iteration has been finished (which may take some time) the threads Returns the result (good way would be a callback) and sets himself into suspended mode.

So this is just a custom Scheduler with prewarmed threads. If you're building the suspend/resume with ManualResetEvents the threads are available nearly instantly.

**Still want more Performance?**

If you're still gaining for a Little more Performance and want be able to tune your resulting System in a more granular manner i would recommend specialized thread pools (like zabbix does it for Monitoring). 
So you don't just assign a bunch of threads which may invoke a custom method to check if a box is reachable via ping or tcp, you assign a seperate pool per Monitoring type.
So in case of icmp (ping) and tcp Monitoring you would create at least two thread pools where the threads contain already the Basic knowlege about "how to check". 
In case of a ping Monitor the thread would be ready and wait with a initialized ping instance which is just waiting for a target to check.
When you take the thread from suspended state it immediately checks the host and Returns the result. afterwards it prepares for sleep (and in this case initializes the Environment for the next run already).
If you're implementing this in a good way you can even reuse resources like sockets.

All in all this Approach enables you to Monitor 3, 35 or even hundrets of boxes without getting into Trouble. Of course Monitoring is still limited and you shouldn't fork thousands of prewarmed threads. that's not the idea behind: the idea is that you've defined Maximum numbers of threads which are ready for use and just waiting to get destinations to check. You don't have to deal with forking issues when initiating a Monitoring for many Hosts - you just have to deal with queuing if you're Monitoring more than you defined concurrency allows (and this may be much higher than Parallel.ForEach which by Default spawns Maximum one thread per core! Check the overloads of the method to increase this amount.)

**Absolute optimization**

If you're still willing to improve the System furthermore get your Scheduler and resource planner not just a Count of prewarmend threads. give him limitations like min 4, max 42 threads. the Scheduler takes starting and stopping additional threads within These borders into account. This is useful if your System decreases Monitoring rates over night and you don't want the suspended threads to hang around.

This would be A+ implementation as you wouldn't just be able to start Monitoring from cold state immediately for at least some Hosts and quickly for many Hosts - you would also give back resources you really don't Need for Long times.

Answer (score 0):

As this seems to be pretty much a dedicated task for the application, I agree that it might make sense to manage the number of threads used for specific tasks by yourself.

Also, it appears that there are a number of stages in your process:

1. Providing the next address(es) to check
2. Determining the time-out to use when checking. The timeout to use might depend on several factors, including whether the address was determined to be unresponsive on the previous check, what it's response time generally is, and, as Dariusz mentioned, if it is on the LAN, extranet, internet, ...
3. Performing the ping
4. Processing and interpreting the ping reply v.s. previous reply status and accumulated status (e.g. update statistics for the address, and potentially even storing this).
5. Issuing "alerts" on (repeated) unresponsiveness
6. Issuing restart commands.

So if you have the stages that can be performed independently clear, using output produced by the previous stage, you might opt for a SEDA (Staged Event Driven Architecture) type of solution, where you can assign a number of dedicated threads to each stage. And stages can be connected to each other using Provider / Producer / Consumer roles for specific items of information that flows through the stages, where there are ProducerConsumerQueues to absorb temporary mismatches (peek loads) and automatic throttling (e.g. too many pending requests for pings will block the producer of ping requests until the consumer performing the pings has sufficiently caught up).

For the basic structure of your "Ping flow", you might then have the following stages:

1. A "PingRequest" producer stage, that is fed by a Provider of IPAddresses and uses a Factory to create the request (so the Factory can determine the time-out for the request from the history and last known status for the IPAddress). It passes the request on to the connected consumer of "PingRequests".
2. A "Pinger" stage, that retrieves PingRequests from its consumer queue, performs the Ping and passes the results on to the connected consumer of "PingResults"
3. A "ResultProcessor" stage, that retrieves PingResults from its consumer queue, updates the status for the IPAddress and passes the results on to the connected consumer of "PingStatus".

After stage 3 possibly you want to additional stages in the same manner for generating alerts, requests for reboots, etc.

Each of these stages may be assigned a dedicated number of threads, and can be quite flexible in making changes to the flow.

A few code examples to illustrate:

```
/// <summary>
/// Coordinates and wires up the processing pipeline.
/// </summary>
public class PingModule : IConsumer<PingStatus>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<IPAddress, PingStatus> _status = new ConcurrentDictionary<IPAddress,PingStatus>();
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancelTokenSource;
    private readonly PingRequestProducerWorkStage _requestProducer;
    private readonly PingWorkStage _pinger;
    private readonly PingReplyProcessingWorkStage _replyProcessor;

    public PingModule(IProvider<IPAddress> addressProvider)
    {
        _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        _requestProducer = new PingRequestProducerWorkStage(1, addressProvider, NextRequestFor, _cancelTokenSource.Token);
        _pinger = new PingWorkStage(4, 10 * 2, _cancelTokenSource.Token);
        _replyProcessor = new PingReplyProcessingWorkStage(2, 10 * 2, _cancelTokenSource.Token);

        // connect the pipeline.
        _requestProducer.ConnectTo(_pinger);
        _pinger.ConnectTo(_replyProcessor);
        _replyProcessor.ConnectTo(this);
    }

    private PingRequest NextRequestFor(IPAddress address)
    {
        PingStatus curStatus;
        if (!_status.TryGetValue(address, out curStatus))
            return new PingRequest(address, IPStatus.Success, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(120));
        if (curStatus.LastResult.TimedOut)
        {
            var newTimeOut = TimeSpan.FromTicks(curStatus.LastResult.TimedOutAfter.Ticks * 2);
            return new PingRequest(address, IPStatus.TimedOut, newTimeOut);
        }
        else
        {
            var newTimeOut = TimeSpan.FromTicks(curStatus.AverageRoundtripTime + 4 * curStatus.RoundTripStandardDeviation);
            return new PingRequest(address, IPStatus.Success, newTimeOut);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

This pipeline could now be easily modified. For example, you might decide that you want to have 2 or 3 parallel "Pinger" stage flows, where one serves the addresses that were previously disconnected, one serves the "slow responders" and one serves the rest. This could be achieved by connecting stage 1 to a consumer that does this routing, and passes a PingRequest on to the correct "Pinger".

```
public class RequestRouter : IConsumer<PingRequest>
{
    private readonly Func<PingRequest, IConsumer<PingRequest>> _selector;

    public RequestRouter(Func<PingRequest, IConsumer<PingRequest>> selector)
    {
        this._selector = selector;
    }
    public void Consume(PingRequest work)
    {
        _selector(work).Consume(work);
    }
    public void Consume(PingRequest work, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        _selector(work).Consume(work, cancelToken);
    }
}

public class PingModule : IConsumer<PingStatus>
{
    // ...
    public PingModule(IProvider<IPAddress> addressProvider)
    {
        _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        _requestProducer = new PingRequestProducerWorkStage(1, addressProvider, NextRequestFor, _cancelTokenSource.Token);
        _disconnectedPinger = new PingWorkStage(2, 10 * 2, _cancelTokenSource.Token);
        _slowAddressesPinger = new PingWorkStage(2, 10 * 2, _cancelTokenSource.Token);
        _normalPinger = new PingWorkStage(3, 10 * 2, _cancelTokenSource.Token);
        _requestRouter = new RequestRouter(RoutePingRequest);
        _replyProcessor = new PingReplyProcessingWorkStage(2, 10 * 2, _cancelTokenSource.Token);

        // connect the pipeline
        _requestProducer.ConnectTo(_requestRouter);
        _disconnectedPinger.ConnectTo(_replyProcessor);
        _slowAddressesPinger.ConnectTo(_replyProcessor);
        _normalPinger.ConnectTo(_replyProcessor);
        _replyProcessor.ConnectTo(this);
    }
    private IConsumer<PingRequest> RoutePingRequest(PingRequest request)
    {
        if (request.LastKnownStatus != IPStatus.Success)
            return _disconnectedPinger;
        if (request.PingTimeOut > TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            return _slowAddressesPinger;
        return _normalPinger;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of an end-around the coding problem, but have you considered using NagiOS or smokeping or another open-source monitoring solution?  These can quickly detect drops in connectivity, and likely have many other features that you might not want to tap out yourself.